# Simple and problematic, double-form ajax posting isn't triggering

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sure my code is broken, can anyone tell where? I cannot use the same form.
I have tried several ways to send 2 POST forms to an action page. But when click the button, the page is reloaded with the updated address bar (click the yname button on the submission form and the address goes to example.com/?yname and not the do.php page)

Please consider the example:

```js
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $("form").each(function(){
        var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "do.php",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data,status) {
               //this will execute when form is submited without errors
           },
           error: function(data, status) {
               //this will execute when get any error
           },
       });
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
 <input type="tel" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" name="yemail" class="c">
 <button id="sub"></button>
</form>

<form id="form2">
 <input type="tel" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="yname" class="b">
 <button id="sub"></button>
</form>
```

Result of tis code:
When click in a form the url address updates with ?yname
Why aren't triggering an action for a do.php page?

Comment: Because the button is submitting the form (a button without `type` is `submit` by default). Add `type="button"` in each button. And repeating `#sub` is a problem, you should use a class instead.

Comment: Thank you @RoyBogado I added the `type` and changed the `sub` to class, there is no action. I even thought it was a browser problem, I tried it in many ways. can i update my snippet with your tips and you try to tell me if something is still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`#id` can not be repeated. Use a `class` instead.
And the line `$(this).parent('form')` gets the form of each `.sub` clicked.

The buttons should be `type="button"` 'couse by default it will be `type="submit"`

> #### TYPE
>
> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are: 
> **submit:**
>   The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if
>   the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a ,
>   or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value. 
>   
> **reset:**
>  The button
>   resets all the controls to their initial values, like . (This behavior tends to annoy users.) 
> **button:** 
> The
>   button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by
>   default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the element's
>   events, which are triggered when the events occur.

[Documentation Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

**EDITED:** for sending all data in one form just delete the `form2`

```js
$(".sub").click(function(){
         //This line is searching the correct form from itself.
        var fd = new FormData($(this).parent('form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "do.php",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data,status) {
               //this will execute when form is submited without errors
           },
           error: function(data, status) {
               //this will execute when get any error
           }
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
 <input type="tel" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" name="yemail" class="c">
 <button type="button" class="sub"></button>
   

 <input type="tel" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="yname" class="b">
 <button type="button" class="sub"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: **Thank you for the very well documented answer.** Worked very well and you helped me to learn. The only problem now is that only one of forms has sent. How to submit data from these 2 forms at the same time? or something that I can use to do it.

I mean, when click on `yemail` button form it sent data from `ymail`
When click on `yname` it sent data from `yname`
What I need is sent data from (`ymail` and `yname`) when click in `yname` button. Any Idea?